# regexp_replace to truncate string at specified character with postgresql

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to get friendly URLs in postgres. Example:

I would like url = https://this-is-the-domain-i-want/?but_not_this#stuff%stuff and url = https://this-is-the-domain-i-want/this-too/?but_not_this#stuff%stuff to return https://this-is-the-domain-i-want/ and https://this-is-the-domain-i-want/this-too/ respectively.

I can successfully use a nested regexp_replace for this:

> REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(url, '\?(.*)', ''), '\%(.*)', ''), '#(.*)', '')

but I was hoping for something cleaner (that wouldn't require iterating over that url multiple times.

I know regex has a `| or`, but I've tried `REGEXP_REPLACE(url, '\?(.*)|\%(.*)|\#(.*)|\_(.*)', '')` with no success.

Comment: Try `REGEXP_REPLACE(url, '[?].*', '')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you just want to remove the query string and fragments, i.e. everything after a `?` including the `?` and analog for `#`.

That would be:

```
regexp_replace(url, '[\?#].*', '');
```

I wouldn't remove `_` and `%` as they can have meaning in the identification of main resource (`_` is just a legal character and `%` introduces an URL encoded character).